# How to make different columns for each elements in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column that contains list of strings (lengths are different) like below:
`df['category']`:

```
category                                                                           | ...
---------
['Grocery & Gourmet Food', 'Cooking & Baking', 'Lard & Shortening', 'Shortening']  | ...
['Grocery & Gourmet Food', 'Candy & Chocolate', 'Mints']                           | ...
['Grocery & Gourmet Food', 'Soups, Stocks & Broths', 'Broths', 'Chicken']          | ...
```

Now, I want to break this category column into different columns for each string element in the list. Is it possible to do using pandas? How I am gonna handle the column names?

I have gone through the answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns), but the difference is my list lengths are not the same always.

My expected output would be something like below:

```
category_1             | category_2       |  category_n  | other_columns 
------------------------------------------------------------------
Grocery & Gourmet Food | Cooking & Baking | Lard & Shortening | ...
...                    | ...              | ...               | ...
```

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your expected output?

Comment: for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57498593/10197418) to the linked question works well with lists of different sizes, column names would be auto-generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['category'].to_list(), columns=[f"category_{i+1}" for i in range(len(df['category'].max()))])
df = pd.concat([df.drop('category', axis=1), df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
               category_1              category_2         category_3  \
0  Grocery & Gourmet Food        Cooking & Baking  Lard & Shortening   
1  Grocery & Gourmet Food       Candy & Chocolate              Mints   
2  Grocery & Gourmet Food  Soups, Stocks & Broths             Broths   

   category_4  
0  Shortening  
1        None  
2     Chicken
```

Edit:

As [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) suggested, it is better to create the columns with their default names and then update them:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df['category'].to_list())
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'category_{x+1}')
df = pd.concat([df.drop('category', axis=1), df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Better create first `df2` with default column names, then update with `df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: f'category_{x+1}')`

Comment: @mozway True, that's actually better. Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: @SpicyPhoenix This edited answer creates another column named `category_1` which is just another copy of the `category` column.

Comment: @sksoumik That's weird. I've just tested it myself and the output is the same as the one I posted. https://i.imgur.com/hpa7R0v.png

Comment: @SpicyPhoenix, sorry. My category column's items were actually `str` not list. That's why it was not working. I converted it to list using `ast`. Now, it's working. Thanks